# Adding random numbers to each number in a column of a table

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I want to add random numbers to each element within the column of a table. This is is what I've been doing, but my approach adds same random number to all elements in that specific column.

```
NewEdge(:,2) = NewEdge(:,2)+ randi(3);
```

How can I add a different random number to each element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NewEdge(:,2) = NewEdge(:,2)+ randi(3,size(NewEdge(:,2)); % Looks pretty
NewEdge(:,2) = NewEdge(:,2)+ randi(3,size(NewEdge,1),1); % Probably faster
```

`randi(3)` is a single scalar. Random, but still one number. You want to add a vector of random numbers, so call `randi(imax,sz1,sz2)`, where `imax` is your maximum allowable integer, `3` in your case, and `sz1,sz2` the sizes of your desired matrix, in this case you want as many rows as contained in `NewEdge`, and only a single column.

Comment: I think `randi(3,size(NewEdge(:,2));` looks prettier :D

Comment: @AnderBiguri right, of course that works. I was a bit in doubt whether you could group arguments like that, but that works the same as in `zeros`, `reshape` etc.

Comment: Hm, the only minor concern I might have with that change is that you're extracting the column from the matrix just to get at its size - so I'd prefer the v1 solution!

Comment: @Edric that is absolutely right. But its not pretty :(